# Kendo UI Scheduler - MVVM set date

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I've been trying to create an object to bind the Date property of the Scheduler control, however the value is never bound unless I create a custom binding.
Is there a way to do it without the custom binding?

I've been trying here: http://dojo.telerik.com/UhexIK/3

by adding the properties to viewModel object or to an options object inside it, but I'm stuck

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As the [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/mvvm) states:

> Kendo UI Scheduler supports the events, source and visible bindings.

So you cannot bind to the `date` configuration field. The syntax `data-date='2017/1/1'` only supports a string as parameter (no variable).

I have tried a number of things on your Dojo link and in my opinion it is just not possible at the moment.